# Select row id from row unmatch

Tags: sql, database

Supose I've this table,

meta:

```
| id | comment_id | key         | value   |
|  1 |      1     | _status     | pending |  
|  2 |      2     | _comment_id |    1    |
|  3 |      2     | _status     | pending |
```

what I want is retrieve the comment_id values from the rows with `_status = pending` that doesn't have a row with `_comment_id =` pointing to itself.

to better explain consider this following pseudo-code.

```
status = getRows( {key: _status, value: pending} );
ids = getRows( {key: _comment_id } )

what_i_want = []
foreach status as comment_status_id:
    if comment_status_id not in ids:
        what_i_want[] = status_id
```

what is the best way to do this ? is it possible to do this using only sql ?

in case of that table should return: [2]

Comment: According to your description, it should return (1) and (2).  Neither have a `_comment_id` referring their own value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `group by` and `having`:

```
select comment_id
from table t
group by comment_id
having sum(case when key = '_status' and value = 'pending' then 1 else 0
           end) > 0 and
       sum(case when key = '_comment_id' and value = cast(comment_id as varchar(255))
                then 1 else 0
           end) = 0;
```

If you are looking for status = "pending", with a comment id, *and* the comment id doesn't point to itself:

```
select comment_id
from table t
group by comment_id
having sum(case when key = '_status' and value = 'pending' then 1 else 0
           end) > 0 and
       sum(case when key = '_comment_id' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when key = '_comment_id' and value = cast(comment_id as varchar(255))
                then 1 else 0
           end) = 0;
```

Comment: this return exactly what i don't want